# Expand bazel command with bazelrc

Tags: bazel

given a bazel command, for example `bazel build //...`, is it possible to see what build command this expands to based on the [bazelrc](https://bazel.build/run/bazelrc)(s)?

`bazelrc`s are great to set default flags, like the default platform to build for setting some variables based on profiles.
They also allow for nested `bazelrc`s, that you can `import` and `try-import` leading to a rather complex expansion of bazel commands via `bazelrc`s.

To verify that the `bazelrc`s did indeed configure the correct things and did not override some flags accidentally, I would love to see the output of what bazel would expand a bazel command to.

Is that possible?

I tried setting `--logging=0` and `--logging=6` with bazel 5.3.0 but see no such output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run your build using the [`--explain`](https://bazel.build/reference/command-line-reference#flag--explain) flag.

Something like

```
bazel build --explain explain.log //...
```

should produce a file `explain.log` where the first line contains the expanded flags.